# Problem when I try to free a pointer vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to learn to free pointer in a  vector, I have read the questions on this page, and follow the answers to write some test code.I grab images from a web camera and first store all the images in memory, after all images are grabbed ,I save all image into jpg format.

Everything works fine at first, I can store the images in memory, and then I can save all of them into jpg. But the problem is, when I try to free all element in the vector, it always gives me some error. It always goes to dbgheap.c:  IsValidHeapPointer. I am quite new to Virtual C++ and C++,so I have no idea why this error happened.

I use OpenCV  to grab images and save images, but I am sure the problem is not about OPENCV but deleting  vector. So maybe I miss something, so can anyone give me some hint?
Thank you very much in advance.
The code somehow likes this :

```
std::vector<IplImage*> images(30);
IplImage* TheImage;
for (int j=0;j<30;j++){
    TheImage=camera.QueryFrame();
    images[j]=(IplImage*)cvClone(TheImage);
    if(cvWaitKey(20)==27)  
        break;
}
cvDestroyWindow("camera");

CString ImagesName;

for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    ImagesName.Format(_T("Image%.3d.jpg"), i);
    cvSaveImage(ImagesName,images[i]);
}


int s=images.size();
for(size_t i = 0; i <s ; ++i)
{
    delete  images[i];// Here should be cvReleaseImage(images[i]);
}
```

/*
for(std::vector::iterator i=images.begin(),endI=images.end();i!=endI;++i)
    {
        delete *i; 
    }
*/

```
images.clear();
```

Comment: What does the documentation for cvClone say that you should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having issues is the image not being created with `new`. OpenCV being C uses `malloc()`. But before trying to call `free()`, use the function provided for this: `cvReleaseImage()`.

Side note: Just because a function called `CreateSomething` returns a pointer doesn't mean you're even able to delete/free the memory it's pointing at. Look at the following code which is perfectly fine but you just can't free that memory yourself. This might look weird, which it is, but such functions might handle their memory using some kind of reserved memory map or whatever.

```
int someint;

int *CreateInt()
{
    return &someint;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario,I forgot it the element is IplImage* ,thanks very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The memory for your images was allocated somewhere inside `cvClone`. I am not an OpenCV expert (this is OpenCV, right?) but I think you're supposed to free them by calling `cvRelease` rather than with `delete`.

Comment: Yes Thanks Gareth,I forgot it the element is IplImage* ,thanks very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
images[j]=(IplImage*)cvClone(TheImage);
```

You freeing a pointer that was not allocated by you. Note how you get it by calling a library function. How do you know that the function uses new to allocate the image, instead of, say, malloc?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I think your final loop will access all 30 vector entries, and not just the ones you initialized.  So, in addition to **deleting** memory that should be **cvReleased**() or something, you might also be trying to **delete** NULL's.

Comment: Thanks Vagrant,I just initialized 30 enries in the vector.but if I initialized 50 entries but I just used 30, I guess images.clear() will delete all other NULLs,am I right? sorry,I am quite new to programming and I am still being confused and try to learn more about programming.

Comment: I'm saying that if you get cvWaitKey(20)==27, then you might break out of the loop before all 30 vector entries are initialized.  If that is the case, then you might try to delete an uninitialized pointer.  Well, it will probably be initialized to 0, but cvRelease will probably choke on that.  Know what I mean?

Comment: Oh yes,thanks Vagrant.I have to do something also there,in case the loop breaks before reaching 30....